# Context null when testing SQLiteOpenHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing

I've found a lot of similar questions, but none that exactly answer my question.
What's the best way to unit test a SQLliteOpenHelper class in android?

My error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
android.content.Context.deleteDatabase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.test.RenamingDelegatingContext.openOrCreateDatabase(RenamingDelegatingContext.java:157)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at uk.co.ticking_clock.reptilekeeper.data.AnimalOperationsTest.pet_defaultEntries(AnimalOperationsTest.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DatabaseOperationsTest extends AndroidTestCase {
private MyDbHelper testDb;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    RenamingDelegatingContext context = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_");
    testDb = MyDbHelper.getInstance(context);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    testDb = null;
}

@Test
public void pet_defaultEntries() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = testDb.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor textDb = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM tableOne", null);

    int expected = 2;
    int actual = textDb.getCount();

    Assert.assertTrue(expected  == actual);

}
}
```

Comment: Your error is coming from a `deleteDatabase()` call. There is no `deleteDatabase()` call in the code in your question. Please post the entire Java stack trace, plus the source code of yours that is referenced in that stack trace. Also, `AndroidTestCase` may not work with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` and has been deprecated in any case. Use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` to get at a `Context` for the application or library code that is being tested.

Comment: expanded stack trace added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getContext()` would appear to be returning `null`. As I noted in a comment, `AndroidTestCase` may not work with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` and has been deprecated in any case. Use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` to get at a `Context` for the application or library code that is being tested.

Comment: `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` was the solutions. I don't see any mention of `AndroidtestCase` being deprecated in the docs thought?

Comment: @DavidFinder: All of the original test classes (e.g., `AndroidTestCase`) are deprecated in the N Developer Preview. Presumably, they will remain deprecated when that turns into the next shipping version of Android.